# How Search Product by manufacture name in magento and get array ? (PHP)

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-manufacturer

How Search Product by manufacture in magento and get array ? (PHP)

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch all products from collection using **addAttributeToFilter()** method to collect only through manufacturer:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer_attribute_code', 'manufacturer_name')->load();
foreach($products as $product){
   $product_name = $product->getName();
}
print_r($product_name);
```

Hope this will help.